# How to make npm use the lowest version that matches all requirements

Tags: npm, dependencies, dependency-management, npm-install

We're using NodeJS for some projects and are faced with an issue that must have a simple solution (seeing as nobody else seems to have the problem).

In the packages.json there are a bunch of dependencies mentioned with a minimum version, each of which may have overlapping dependencies of their own. The default way a dependency is added is using the ^ operator which seems to mean 'compatible with' or 'same major version, but minor versions may differ'.

The way I understand npm to work is on `npm install` to take the highest minor version available that matches. Unfortunately 'compatible with' is not quite as enforced as you'd hope.

The situation this puts us in is that for instance on a developer machine version 1.1.0 is installed, but between development and publishing a new version 1.2.0, that has a bug, is introduced. On our build machine a fresh build is made which ends up using 1.2.0 and we've introduced a bug that wasn't there in development.

We tried changing the ^ operator to = for instance, but this gives us trouble when dependencies have subdependencies that aren't compatible with the requested version.

All in all I'm a bit confused, but this thing keeps biting us anytime something changes since the development machines don't do anything on `npm install` if the package is already there, but the build machine always gets fresh copies.

I know from NuGet that it always takes the **lowest** version that matches all combined requirements. Since this is always the same for a given set of dependencies, I much prefer this approach. Is there a way to make npm work like this too?

Comment: are you trying to lock your software to a specific dependency version ?

Answer (score -2):

To answer my own question:

npm has introduced a new command `npm ci` which does something similar to `npm install` but enforces that the specific versions are used that were also used when a package was initially added by using the package-lock file.

See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci for more information